# How do i stream a variable to a file Node JS?

Tags: node.js, save, streamwriter

I need to save a response to a file. The response is a zip file returned from a server which is recieved as a blob. I need to save to blob as a zip file on my local machine. The application itself is Electron, and the file needs to be stored in the background (without bothering the user). Filetype is zip ( and needs to be unzipped after this.

```
const writer = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(dir, 'files.zip'));
                writer.on('pipe', (src) => {
                  console.log('Something is piping into the writer.');
                });
                writer.end('This is the end\n');
                writer.on('finish', () => {
                  console.log('All writes are now complete.');
                });

writer.pipe(new Blob([response.data]));
```

Best i can do gives a 1kb corrupt file. I have read the node docs, but i can't get it to work.

ANY response is greatly appreciated, and please elaborate if you can.  I feel like i need to use some type of buffer.

Comment: What is the http server module that you using?

Comment: I'm getting a response.data trough an Axios response.Adding on; I am able to do two other things ( related) use a 'save as' function where the user saves it . and use the JSZip librabry to re-zip and save the file.  So the recieved data is correct. So in short; Axios

Comment: Im sorry if I misunderstood. As of [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) module that I found it is a client version. Are you using axios in server side?

Comment: No this is client side (Electron, VueJS, Axios).  The server is plain PHP which returns the zip file. If you need any information please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figured finally it out.

Instead of a return type of `Blob` i had to return an `arraybuffer`. Next step is using the JSzip library and convert my function to async.

Final result:

```
//Create JSZip object to read incoming blob
const zip = new JSZip;

try {
  //Await unpacked arrayBuffer
  const zippedFiles = (await zip.loadAsync(response.data, { createFolders: true })).files;

  for (const file of Object.values(zippedFiles)) {
    if (file.dir) {
      await mkdirAsync(path.join(dir, file.name), { recursive: true });
    } else {
        file
          .nodeStream()
          .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path.join(dir, file.name)))
          .on("finish", console.log);
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
   throw MeaningfulError;
 }
```

In short: This function takes an arraybuffer (of type .zip) and unpacks it to your system.

- `response.data` is the arraybuffer (which needs to be unpacked).
- `dir` is the directory in which the content needs to be unpacked.

And that's all you need!

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
var a = document.createElement("a");
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.style = "display: none";

var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
a.href = url;
a.download = fileName;
a.click();
window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
```

Comment: I tried it, including some tinkering with the response and location. But there is no output.  I do however get a deprecation warning `DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.`

Comment: Thank you. I have tried it, and now there is no response whatsoever. No error or succes output. I have tried console logging around every statement ( the medieval way, and it seems the code doesnt get passed the `new Buffer` statement.

Comment: thats odd. Can run `console.log(response.data)` and `console.log(typeof response.data)` and comment the output

Comment: Ofcourse : `console.log(response.data)` produces `object`.  And the `typeof` produces `Blob(146757) {size: 146757, type: "application/octet-stream"}`

Comment: Seems like you are dealing with browser Blob, so node fs module won't help. Try the above code and let me know what is the state.

Comment: At this point there is no download ( I havent provided you with enough information, my apologies. )  But there is an A tag at the bottom of my 'page' as expected. I have edited my question to provide a little extra info.  The download + eventual unzip needs to happen in the background of the local machine. I'm using Electron.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188814/discussion-between-user1692823-and-janith-kasun).